# Any code problem putting single phase 240 and three phase 240 in same outlet box

Tags: electrical

I am running both single phase 240 and three phase 240 in my shop. I discovered that each of the locking, industrial round plugs for these (L14-30R and L15-30R) can fit in one double gang box. Is there any code problem with doubling them up? The single phase 240 comes from the breaker, and the three phase 240 comes from a three phase converter fed from the same panel.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, the plugs may not physically clear when installed next to each other at 1-gang spacing.  I would recommend using 2 separate boxes for that reason.

That said, you can put both voltages in the same junction box, **but you must clearly mark them to distinguish them**.

Comment: Having 3phase means you have single phase available...

Comment: @SolarMike Not necessarily, OP might have 240V plain (non-wild-leg) delta and 120/240V split-phase.

Comment: Ok, 3phase I have seen in two different countries is 3 phases and a neutral plus earth...

Comment: Wouldn't the  delta voltage of a 3 phase system with 120V star voltage be ca. 208V, and not 240V?

Comment: @xeeka there are multiple three phase systems in North America.  208Y/120 is the system you refer to, and it's generally only used to feed wye connected or single phase loads (although it is possible to feed delta connected loads from it).  The other systems all use delta connected *sources*, and are delta systems as a result with no star point.  (In a North American delta system, the neutral point may be a center-tap on one winding (as in wild leg delta), one of the corners of the delta (as in corner grounded delta), or nonexistent (ungrounded delta).)

Comment: @SolarMike Yes, 240V3ph often has neutral stuck halfway down one leg, allowing 120/240V split-phase along that leg.  This is called "wild leg" because it's asymmetrical.  However, given that there's already a 120/240V service present, the 240V service doesn't need to be wild-leg, and may be plain delta in some fashion as TPE describes.

Comment: If it matters, the OP says the 3-phase comes from a converter. Its on a different breaker, and the "third leg" is synthesized by the phase converter.

Comment: @ScottFranco yeah -- phase-converter output is delta-connected, and generally considered equivalent to a high-leg delta, even, as the idler's motoring winding is in parallel with the center-tapped secondary of the service transformer.  (If you fire up the converter then use a voltmeter to measure from the manufactured phase to ground, you'll read about 208V vs. 120V to ground for the other two phases, as you'd expect in a high leg service.)